# Restrict logins from restoring backups into some databases - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup, permissions, restore

I'm looking for a way to restrict some logins (not users, see more below) from restoring backups into some specific, already existing databases.

I've read a couple articles on database permissions and a lot more can be but since the whole databases are being restored (using the WITH REPLACE flag), user permissions get overwritten (?) at every restore, so we're using just logins instead of users.

Server is running SQL Server 2016.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do the logins **must** be able to restore backups if the database doesn't exist? Because it would be easier to just deny restore to those logins.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know the current permissions for these logins. Are they db_owner of the databases in question? Or sysadmin on the instance?

Comment: Those users should be able to restore backups into a selection of already existing databases. They currently have sysadmin permission (yeah, I know) but their logins privileges can be adjusted to match this specific requirement.

Comment: @Leon_R, a sysadmin can't be denied or granted any privileges: it owns the instance.

Comment: I know that. That's why I added the trailing comment. :)